# Spring Cloud Gateway with Eureka getting 504 (Gateway Time-out)

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

Let's assume I have one **Eureka Server**, one **Spring Cloud Gateway**  and one **ServiceA** running with two instances.

When I deploy an updated version of the service, for a brief period of time, eureka will hold four instances for **ServiceA**, the ones that no longer exist and the ones that were just started.

Until Eureka evicts the two instances that are no longer valid, on the gateway, Ribbon will still load balance among those that do not longer exist, generating `ConnectTimeoutException` and consequently `504 (Gateway Time-out)`. I have configured those routes in the Gateway with the following *retry* configuration.

```
val retry = RetryGatewayFilterFactory.RetryConfig()
                 .setExceptions(ConnectException::class.java)
```

And this allows ribbon to retry immediately when the exception is `ConnectException: Connection refused` but it won't retry when it is a `ConnectTimeoutException`.

I could tweak the refresh intervals for ribbon and eureka clients but I rather don't touch those.

So, I have two questions regarding this.

- How can I capture the timeout inside the filter?
- Is there a better way to handle this in order to achieve zero downtime?

Thanks

Comment: are you using Hystrix?

Comment: @spencergibb not yet no, should I for this?

Answer (score 1):

try `ribbon.retryableStatusCodes=404,502,504`

---

Update:

First in my mind, `ConnectException` should associate with code `502` and `504` is `SocketTimeoutException`. Please correct me if wrong.

Sorry, not look more into cloud gateway, but its LB can use Ribbon optionally.

Let's asseume you are using Ribbon and `OKHttp` via `ribbon.OkHttp.enabled`.

`OkHttpRibbonConfiguration` will init a `OkHttpLoadBalancingClient` bean, which executes request. In its `execute()`, it creates an `RetryCallback` anonymous implementation object first during each request execution. The `RetryCallback` is responsible for executing request and retrying execution.

Let's go to the logic of `RetryCallback`. After response received, it checks the response status code if retryable or not. If `RetryTemplate` class exists in class loader, the implementation of `loadBalancedRetryPolicyFactory` is `RibbonLoadBalancedRetryPolicyFactory`. It is used to create the `RibbonLoadBalancedRetryPolicy` object (`retryPlicy` below) .

`executeWithRetry()` create a `RetryTemplate` with `RetryPolicy`. (precondition, retry enabled in spring cloud gateway by setting request as retryable).

```
public OkHttpRibbonResponse execute(...) throws Exception {
    final LoadBalancedRetryPolicy retryPolicy = loadBalancedRetryPolicyFactory.create(this.getClientName(), this);
    ...
    final Request request = newRequest.toRequest();
    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    if(retryPolicy.retryableStatusCode(response.code())) {
        ResponseBody responseBody = response.peekBody(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        response.close();
        throw new OkHttpStatusCodeException(RetryableOkHttpLoadBalancingClient.this.clientName,
                            response, responseBody, newRequest.getURI());
    }
    return new OkHttpRibbonResponse(response, newRequest.getUri());        
}    

private OkHttpRibbonResponse executeWithRetry(...) throws Exception {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = loadBalancedBackOffPolicyFactory.createBackOffPolicy(this.getClientName());
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy == null ? new NoBackOffPolicy() : backOffPolicy);
    RetryListener[] retryListeners = this.loadBalancedRetryListenerFactory.createRetryListeners(this.getClientName());
    if (retryListeners != null && retryListeners.length != 0) {
        retryTemplate.setListeners(retryListeners);
    }
    boolean retryable = isRequestRetryable(request); //HERE
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy == null || !retryable ? new NeverRetryPolicy()
            : new RetryPolicy(request, retryPolicy, this, this.getClientName()));
    return retryTemplate.execute(callback, recoveryCallback);
}

private boolean isRequestRetryable(ContextAwareRequest request) {
    return request.getContext() == null ? true :
        BooleanUtils.toBooleanDefaultIfNull(request.getContext().getRetryable(), true);
}
```

In `retryableStatusCode()`, it checks the retryableStatusCodes if contains response status code or not.

```
public class RibbonLoadBalancedRetryPolicy implements LoadBalancedRetryPolicy {
    public static final IClientConfigKey<String> RETRYABLE_STATUS_CODES = new CommonClientConfigKey<String>("retryableStatusCodes") {};
    ....
    List<Integer> retryableStatusCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        public RibbonLoadBalancedRetryPolicy(String serviceId, RibbonLoadBalancerContext context, ServiceInstanceChooser loadBalanceChooser,
                                         IClientConfig clientConfig) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.lbContext = context;
        this.loadBalanceChooser = loadBalanceChooser;
        String retryableStatusCodesProp = clientConfig.getPropertyAsString(RETRYABLE_STATUS_CODES, "");
        String[] retryableStatusCodesArray = retryableStatusCodesProp.split(",");
        for(String code : retryableStatusCodesArray) {
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                try {
                    retryableStatusCodes.add(Integer.valueOf(code.trim()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    //TODO log
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean retryableStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        return retryableStatusCodes.contains(statusCode);
    }
}
```

If contained, then throw `OkHttpStatusCodeException` which extends `RetryableStatusCodeException`. And `RibbonRecoveryCallback` catches this exception, check exception is implementation of `RetryableStatusCodeException` or not. If yes, then the `RetryTemplate` continues retrying. Or, throw the unretryable Expcetion to interrupt the retrying.

Comment: Try : explaining your answer.

Comment: @Anthony, last answer is from mobile phone. Just append more.